# Autofixer uses a different PostCSS version than my current version and it is causing an error. How do I resolve this?

Tags: webpack, gatsby, postcss

I am porting my site from create-react-app to gatsby. I have added gatsby as a dependency but now when I run `gatsby develop` I get the following error:

`Unknown error from PostCSS plugin. Your current PostCSS version is 6.0.23, but autoprefixer uses 7.0.23. Perhaps this is the source of the error below.`

I'm not very familiar with webpack but my understanding is that this is as a result of its configuration? So far I have tried to work around this by using yarn workspaces to essentially force the `css-loader` package to depend on the same PostCSS version that autofixer does.

My best guess at a solution would deal with reconfiguring webpack but I have no clue how to go about this. Searches also not yielding any helpful results. I'd really appreciate help with this as well as an explanation of what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

PostCSS version in gatsby is 6.0, but in create-react-app is 7.0...
You should specify you PostCSS config
first, install the `gatsby-plugin-postcss` and then write in gatsby-config.js

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Gatsby`,
  },
 plugins: [
  {
    resolve: `gatsby-plugin-postcss`,
    options: {
      cssLoaderOptions: {
        camelCase: false,
      },
    },
  },
]
}
```

by this code you specify the version of PostCSS to 7.0. but you need to make it visible in your pages, so you should create a `postcss.config.js` and the these lines

```
const postcssPresetEnv = require(`postcss-preset-env`)

module.exports = () => ({
  plugins: [
    postcssPresetEnv({
      stage: 0,
    }),
  ],
})
```